# Android asynctask and android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem in my android app, I use a AsyncTask for connecting a online bbdd. This is my indobackground

```
 protected ResultSet doInBackground(String...params) {
    boolean login = false;
    String input = params[1];   
    try{
        Connection conn;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(ipServidorMySQL, usuarioMySQL, contrasenaMySQL);

        rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery();*/
        PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(input);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        return rs;

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is the onPostExecute

```
 protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet rs){


    MainActivity.rs=rs;
    if(pd != null)
        pd.dismiss();
    MainActivity m= new MainActivity();
    m.useRS(rs);


}
```

But in my useRS I try to start activity and I have this error 
android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)

This is my users function

```
 public void useRS(ResultSet r){
    rs = r;
    try {
       if(rs!=null && rs.next()==true){
           Log.i("Nombre", r.getString("apellidos"));

          Intent i = new Intent(c, Reservas.class);
           i.putExtra("nombre", r.getString("nombre"));
           i.putExtra("apellidos", r.getString("apellidos"));
           startActivity(i);
           tv3.setText(r.getString("apellidos"));

       }
       else {
           Log.i("SIn log", "sin log");
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
           toast.show(); 
       }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

The users in in my mainactivity
 c is a context on mainactivity

```
   private Context c = this;
```

All works form mi since I put the Intent for start activity, every data goes fine... Anyone can help me???

Ty and sorry for my english

Comment: never use new operator with class that extends Activity ... learn Activity's lifecycle ... stop using jdbc on android ... even if you fix this error, still "using" ResultSet still will be using network on main thread

Comment: So Can i make the thing that i want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer, is pass the context to the asynctask by parameter, and then return the same context to the users function.

^^